# How to use $_GET in class php

Tags: php, class

How to use $_GET in class php? I tried to do like this:

```
class UploadHandler
{
   public $a = $_GET['size'];
}
```

It always gives me an error

Comment: What error message do you get?

Answer (score 4):

Try :

```
class UploadHandler 
{
    public $a;
    function __construct() {
        $this->a = isset($_GET['size']) ? $_GET['size'] : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This. You cannot assign a dynamic variable in a class declaration. You need to use a method (be it inside or outside the class) to do so.

Comment: nicely done, +1 for ternary operator -- oh and getting it right

Comment: Sébastien, a __construct() is a method?

Answer (score 0):

Is your goal to get the size of a file upload?  If so, you'll want to use the $_FILES variable.  http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php   Specifically, http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Technically there is no reason a class can't access a global variable.  Best practices might suggest, however, that your controller/gateway pull the data and pass it to the class.  e.g.

```
<?
    $uploaded_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

    $UploadHandler = new UploadHandler();
    $permanent_local_path = $UploadHandler->saveFileSomewhere($uploaded_file);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class UploadHandler
{
    public $a;
    public function __construct(){
        if(isset($_GET['size']){
            $this->a = $_GET['size'];
        }else{
            $this->a = null // or maybe 0
        }
    }
}
```